# PHP www-authenticate Basic Popup Loop Issue

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, http, www-authenticate

Since two days I try to find my issue in a simple sample code:

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']}.</p>";
    echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
}

?>
```

The Auth Popup open fine, I send User and Password. But the popup open again and again. If I cancel the popup the 401 message will displayed correctly.

I tried to fill a .htaccess with

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization},QSA,L]
```

But this change nothing. Thank you for any ideas to solve this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What stack are you using on PHP? Assuming that it's PHP-CGI, try the following in your .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>
```

Make sure, that `mod_rewrite` is avaliable on the server and .htaccess files got parsed (`AllowOverride` must be set to all in `httpd.conf`).

Depending on your infrastructure, there may be some kind of proxy that drops the auth-header. For a clean testing environment, I recommend a local Apache2 installation. Stacks like [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/de/index.html) provide full development areas out of the box.